# How to simulate this multidimensional array code snippet by line,

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to understand how this works, I appreciate those who can help me, this is merely a part of the program itself,I only posted the part wherein I'm having problems of simulating.

```
public static void outputArray(int[][] array) {



        int[] colSum =new int[array[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){   
        int  sum=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){   

        sum = sum + array[i][j]; >

        colSum[j] += array[i][j]; // <--- how this thing works
       }
         System.out.println("Print the sum of rows = " + sum);  
        }  
           for(int k=0;k<colSum.length;k++){  
          System.out.println("Print the sum of columns =" + colSum[k]);  
         } 

          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array you described ( int[][] ) is so-called "jagged array" or "array of arrays" It's different from regular multidimensional array ( syntax int[,]).

The line you commented asking for explanation (shown below)

```
colSum[j] += array[i][j]; // <--- how this thing works
```

essentially means:

```
colSum[j] = colSum[j] +array[i][j];
```

Hope this will help. Rgds,

Comment: thank you Sir, I was asked to simulate that line and I've been searching in the internet, and I'm having no luck finding how to explain it . . I appreciate your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know about operators in java.

```
int x = 1; // x is 1

x += 2; // same as x = x + 2;

x -= 2 // same as x = x - 2;

x *= 2 // same as x = x * 2;

x /= 2 // same as x = x / 2;
```

Kindly consult [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm) for more info on java operators